# How to implement a table with multirow and multicolumn in latex

Tags: tables

How can I create a table like this in latex?
It is included multirow and multicolumn.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The documentation of the [`multirow` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) contains some examples to start with.  For good construction of the partial rules, see the [`booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).  Your question would be greatly improved by including your attempt to code such a table.

Answer (score 1):

[image: MEW]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{3cm}>{\centering}p{0.3\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.3\textwidth}}
\toprule
One  & Two & Tree\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multirow{6}{3cm}{This is a multirow cell for some long text that you want expand in
six rows} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{This is a multicolumn cell}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-3} 
 & x1 & x2\tabularnewline
 & x4 & x5\tabularnewline
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Another multicolum cell}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-3} 
 & x1 & x2\tabularnewline
 & x4 & x5\tabularnewline
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```