# Creating special table

Tags: tables, tabularx

How can I create a table such as following: I do not know how can I have A and B in the middle of four rows ?[image]

Comment: The `multirow` package is done for that. It may require some adjustment.

Comment: Also, another question from you on this very topic: [How to implement a table with multirow and multicolumn in latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129456/how-to-implement-a-table-with-multirow-and-multicolumn-in-latex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
X                  & xx & x & x & x \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{A} & x  & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-5} 
                   & x  & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-5} 
                   & x  & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-5} 
                   & x  & x & x & x \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{B} & x  & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-5} 
                   & x  & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-5} 
                   & x  & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-5} 
                   & x  & x & x & x \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: If you don't like the lines:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
X                  & xx & x & x & x \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{A} & x  & x & x & x \\
                   & x  & x & x & x \\
                   & x  & x & x & x \\
                   & x  & x & x & x \\[1ex]
\multirow{4}{*}{B} & x  & x & x & x \\
                   & x  & x & x & x \\
                   & x  & x & x & x \\
                   & x  & x & x & x
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Is the OP asking for all those horizontal and vertical lines?

Comment: Well, they can be very easily removed from the code provided (see my edit above). I thought the focus of the question was more about having "A and B in the middle of four rows".

Comment: In my view, all those extra lines simply create clutter and thus actually make it harder to find the two crucial parts, which are the `\multirow` instructions.

Comment: Check my edit above.

Comment: Much better... :-) I've taken the liberty of editing your second example to make it approximate the OP's sketch more closely.